# DensityPlot command in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The info for DensityPlot says that the "default generates colorized grayscale output, in which larger values are shown lighter." What on earth is colorized grayscale? Is there a way to make it truly grayscale without the blue and purple colors that it generates? And when I do it, it appears a little pixellated. Is there a way to evaluate it at more points so that it doesnt look so choppy?

Answer (score 4):

By colorized grayscale, I think they mean that it's monochrome, or maybe bichromatic - that is, there's a linear scale from one color to another, rather than fully varying across the whole color space. It's not a very good term, I agree.

Specifying `ColorFunction->GrayLevel` should give you pure grayscale. This is distinct from the built-in gradient GrayTones (`ColorFunction->"GrayTones"`), which appears to stop a bit short of pure black and white on the ends and is a bit warm. There are plenty of other built-in gradients - see the return value of ColorData["Gradients"]. You can also specify your own function, of course - it will take as input a real number from 0 to 1, and should return a color specification, e.g. the return values of `GrayLevel`, `RGBColor`, `Hue`, or `CMYKColor`.

To make it less choppy, as with basically all plotting functions, try specifying a higher value for `PlotPoints` (the number of initial sampling points) or `MaxRecursion` (how many times it can resample).